# Swing unwritten field warning (Java)

Tags: java, swing, awt, findbugs

I have findBugs installed and get a bug warning in the actionPerformed method at if statement

```
if (source == this.temp)
```

The warning says there is an unwritten field. The program still compiles but hangs when I click on the button called temp.

I thought I had already correctly initialized that field. Can someone direct me on where I messed up please? Thanks

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane; 
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import components.simplereader.SimpleReader;
import components.simplereader.SimpleReader1L;

/**
 * View class.
 *
 * @author Redacted
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public final class PasswordManagerView1 extends JFrame
    implements PasswordManagerView {

private JButton temp;

/**
 * controller.
 */
private PasswordManagerController controller;

/**
 * Jpanel.
 */

/**
 * Useful constants.
 */
private Dimension maxSize;
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public PasswordManagerView1() {
    super("Password Manager");
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    //Initial JPanel creation
    tabbedPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    //tabbedPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    this.maxSize = new Dimension(700, 300);
    tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(this.maxSize);
    this.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

    //Initial JTabbedPane creation

    //Tab creation
    JComponent panel1 = this.makeTextPanel("temp1");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("lock-icon.png");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Add Password", icon, panel1,
            "Adds a password to the vault");
    JComponent panel2 = this.makeTextPanel("temp2");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Delete Password", icon, panel2,
            "Deletes a password from the vault");
    JComponent panel3 = this.makeTextPanel("temp3");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Password Vault", icon, panel3,
            "View the passwords in the vault");
    JComponent panel4 = this.makeInfoPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Info/Settings", icon, panel4,
            "View settings and program info");
    JButton temp = new JButton("Hey");
    panel1.add(temp);
    temp.addActionListener(this);
    //Pack up
    this.pack();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

private JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
    filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    panel.add(filler);
    return panel;
}

private JComponent makeInfoPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    StringBuilder toPrint = new StringBuilder();
    SimpleReader in = new SimpleReader1L("data/Notice.txt");
    while (!in.atEOS()) {
        toPrint.append(in.nextLine() + "\n");
    }
    String toPrintString = toPrint.toString();
    JTextArea noticeText = new JTextArea(toPrintString);
    noticeText.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane noticeTextScroll = new JScrollPane(noticeText);
    panel.add(noticeTextScroll);
    in.close();
    return panel;

}

@Override
public void registerObserver(PasswordManagerController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    //Wait cursor
    this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

    //What button was pressed
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == this.temp) {
        this.controller.processTestEvent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor you have this bit of code:

```
JButton temp = new JButton("Hey");
panel1.add(temp);
```

It defines a local `temp` variable which shadows the member - remove `JButton` so that it uses the class member:

```
temp = new JButton("Hey");
panel1.add(temp);
```

Comment: Ah such a simple mistake. Thank you. Can I ask, in your opinion, if this code looks to be decently styled?

Comment: @frillybob: that's more of a question for code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - but IMO numbers in names are a big no-no, comments don't add much to what the code does (although it's OK if you're learning), and all that groups of code (for example tab creation) could use their own functions.

Comment: @mszymborski FYI any question that mentions a bug or something not working the way it should on [codereview.se] gets closed within minutes. But yeah once it works it should be posted on CR for feedback on any/all aspects of the code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I meant after the bug (and others, if present) are fixed, obviously, but thanks for keeping an eye on that.

Comment: @mszymborski Thanks for the codereview link. I'll head over there soon. However, by numbers in names are you referring the class name that has a number being implemented off an interface that doesn't have a number? That is the way I was taught. Or are you referring to temp1, temp2, temp3? If so those are simply temporary.

Comment: @frillybob what's easier to understand? `panel1`, `panel2`, `panel3`, or `topPanel`, `bottomPanel` and `contentPanel`? What's `temp3` used for? Or was it `temp2`? By giving things (ALL the things, even the petty ones!) meaningful names, you make your own life easier, and that of whoever reads your code in the future.

Comment: @frillybob - basically what Mat's Mug said, as to interface-implementation problem you can add `Impl` at the end, which is still meh but much better than `1`.